# Dimension reduction and isoperimetric inequality

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, isoperimetric-problems, geometric-inequalities

$\newcommand{\II}{\mathit{II}}$The isoperimetric inequality $\II_n$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$ is
$$\frac{{\rm vol}_nU}{{\rm vol}_nB_n}\le\left(\frac{{\rm vol}_{n-1}\partial U}{{\rm vol}_{n-1}\partial B_n}\right)^{\frac n{n-1}}$$
where $B_n$ is the unit ball.

> Now, let us pretend that we ignore $\II_{n-1}$. Is it possible to retrieve it from $\II_n$ by some dimensional reduction ?

I acknowledge that my question is a bit vague. But dimensional reduction is used in various topics of Analysis. For instance the fundamental solution for the wave operator  in $1+2$ variables is obtained from that in $1+3$ variables, thanks to a rather simple DR.

Mind a difficulty: if we write $\II_n$ in the form ${\rm vol}_nU\le c_n({\rm vol}_{n-1}\partial U)^{\frac n{n-1}}$, then $c_n$ involves a power of $\pi$ which depends drastically upon the parity of $n$. Thus the DR, which induces a transfer $c_n\mapsto c_{n-1}$, must reflect a difference between the cases $n$ odd or $n$ even.

Comment: Could you sketch how DR works for the wave operator? And doesn’t parity play an important role there, too?

Comment: @DeaneYang: A solution to the wave equation that is constant in the $x_3$ direction has its trace to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^2$ as a solution to the 1+2 wave equation, so you get the 1+2 fundamental solution by integrating the 1+3 fundamental solution in the $x_3$ direction.